# How do I select an image within two <div> tags?

Tags: html, css

Code is as follows:

```
<div id="compare_view" align="center">

    <div id="compv-navbar">
        <img src="image1.png"> | <img src="image2.png"> | <img src="image3.png"> | Text can be here
    </div>    
</div>
```

I would like to be able to manipulate all of the images within the 'compv-navbar' div.

I know I could give each image a unique ID and select them that way, but I want to manipulate all the images within that compv-navbar div at the same time.

Edit: Sorry, I would like to select it with CSS. I thought it was obvious from the tags.

Comment: Select them using what? CSS? JavaScript? Some other language? Please be more specific with your problem.

Comment: I retagged to remove the JavaScript tag.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
#compare_view #compv-navbar img { }
```

The first `id` isn't really necessary but makes it more specific and linear-like. You can go ahead and just use `#compv-navbar img` if you want.

<del>If you want to manipulate with javascript, `getElementById` on `#compv-navbar` and `getElementsByTagName('img')` using that as a context.</del>

<del>jQuery-wise it would be `$('#compv-navbar img')`</del>

Comment: +1 for clean answer. Might be worth adding the direct descendant notation to your answer so it is even more complete:

#compare_view>#compv-navbar>img{}

Comment: It wouldn't work in IE6 and I still have to code for that so I'll leave it as is :)

Answer (score 1):

```
#compv-navbar img { 'your schnizzzle' }
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the JQuery "each" method: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/

Answer (score 0):

```
/*
query for id compv-navbar and populate NodeList collection with all <img> children
NOTE: since ids _required_ to be unique within the document, asking for compare_view first is redundant
*/
var nodeList = document.getElementById( 'compv-navbar' ).getElementsByTagName( 'IMG' );
for ( var i = 0; i < nodeList.length; i++ )
  nodeList[ i ].title = 'Here is my image!'
```

huh, no longer has JS flavour?

```
#compare_view>#compv-navbar>img { content: "here WAS my image" }
```

Again, selector is over-specific